# How to set the play order of a beamer?

Tags: beamer

i want to show my problem with an example

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\frametitle{Cryptography}
\item stream cipher
\item block cipher 
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

what i want to do is when i go to the next page i want first show `\item stream cipher` in order to show what i'm going to say.  who can help me?

Comment: Do you want a page after showing the first item, then to go back to the itemize page, or do you just want the itemize to appear one line at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `label=<name>` as an option for `frame`, you can use `<name>` as a target for `\hyperlink`; in the following example, each item on the first frame is a hyperlink to a different frame, in which you can describe the concept. Additionally, each of the explanatory frames has a "Go back" button (another hyperlink) allowing you to return to the enumerated list:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[label=init]
\frametitle{Cryptography}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \hyperlink{stream}{stream cipher}
\item \hyperlink{block}{block cipher}
\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label=stream]
\frametitle{Description of stream cipher}
test for stream

\vfill
\hyperlink{init}{\beamerbutton{Go back}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label=block]
\frametitle{Description of block cipher}
test for block
\vfill
\hyperlink{init}{\beamerbutton{Go back}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

After discussion in chat:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
  \frametitle{Outline}
  \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Cryptography}
\subsection{Stream cipher}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Stream cipher}
 Description for stream cipher.
\end{frame}
\subsection{Block cipher}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Block cipher}
 Description for block cipher.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i'm sorry it's not what i want. i want to jump to item 1, and show it alone

Comment: @Alex in the first slide item 1 is alone. Please describe in more detail exactly what you want.

Comment: it's somewhat like highlight "stream cipher" and then go to show what stream cipher is. @GonzaloMedina

Comment: @ALex Ah, now I see. Let me update my answer.

Comment: @Alex please see my updated answer; in the first frame, each item is a hyperlink to another frame where you can place the description, Is it something like that waht you want?

Comment: almost like that but i want to show it like PPT, in your way it's not convenient

Comment: @Alex I have no idea what PPT is. Please explain.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10437/discussion-between-alex-and-gonzalo-medina)

Comment: although it's still not what i want, but it is good enough thank you very much..